# I want to inflate an xml file into MainActivity

Tags: java, android, xml

I have an xml file named " `Editt.xml` ",I want to inflate `@+id/myEditText` into MainActivity every time I click an Button from the `activty_main` named " `@+id/Button01` "

" Editt.xml " is this :

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>


<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/myEditText"
    android:layout_weight="1" />   </LinearLayout>
```

and " activity_main "

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<Button
    android:text="Button01"
    android:id="@+id/Button01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
<ScrollView
    android:layout_below="@id/Button01"
    android:id="@+id/scrollview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/tableRow">



 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/gamehistory"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Use layout inflater to call the edit.xml then use addview method to add the view in your linear layout

Answer (score 0):

```
View v = getInflater().inflate(Editt.xml,null);

LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.layout.game_layout);
linearLayout.addView(v);
```